# Zend Framework - Doctrine2 - Repository Query Caching

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm looking at Caching and how to use it in Doctrine.

I've got the following in my Zend Framework Bootstrap.php:

```
// Build Configuration
$orm_config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

// Caching
$cacheOptions = $options['cache']['backendOptions'];
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache();
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect($cacheOptions['servers']['host'], $cacheOptions['servers']['port']);
$cache->setMemcache($memcache);
$orm_config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$orm_config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$orm_config->setResultCacheImpl($cache);
```

I'm running a very simple query on my DB using:

```
self::_instance()->_em->getRepository('UserManagement\Users')->find('1');
```

And I'm not sure if I'm using caching properly, because with it on (as
per the above config) the query seems to take twice as long to execute
as with it disabled, is this right?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 4):

I seem to have sorted this myself, sort of related to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841281/doctrine-2-cache-can-i-use-cache-with-repositoryfind). Basically, from what I understand a repository query like:

```
self::_instance()->_em->getRepository('UserManagement\Users')->find('1');
```

Will not cache the results. If the same query is executed again throughout the script processing, it will not perform the search and use the result it has in memory - this isn't the same as real caching, in my case using Memcache.

The only way to achieve this, is to override the Doctrine EntityRepository find() method in a custom repository with something like:

```
public function find($id)
{
    // Retrieve an instance of the Entity Manager
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('u')
       ->from('UserManagement\Users', 'u')
       ->where('u.id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id', $id);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $query->useResultCache(TRUE);
    $result = $query->getSingleResult();
    return $result;
}
```

Notably, the most important line from the above is `$query->useResultCache(TRUE);` - this informs the Application to cache the results.

Hope this helps.